# Multiple array filter conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sorry this is very easy but my mind is maybe playing me tricks...

I'm trying to perform a multiple array filter condition but getting an error, am I missing something?

```
var Array = cars.filter(
        (cars) => fields !== 'toyota' ||
        (cars) => fields !== 'bmw'
)
```

This works (1 filter condition)

```
var Array = cars.filter((cars) => fields !== 'toyota')
```

Comment: What error do you get? You should name the variables with lowercase: var arr , instead of Array, as Array is reserved word - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: The correct way should be comparing `cars !== 'value'` if your parameter is named `cars`. 

Now, I think the solution is:

    `var array = cars.filter((cars) => cars !== 'toyota' || cars !== 'bmw')`

Or using `.includes()`:

    `var array = cars.filter((cars) => ['toyota','bmw'].includes(cars))`


Finally, I would recommend you to use `const` or `let` on `Array` declaration, instead of `var`.

Nice coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one function. I think you want to use `&&` instead of `||` in this case. Here is an example:

```
var Array = cars.filter((car) => car !== 'toyota' && car !== 'bmw')
```

Comment: This is **well** covered by previous questions and answers.

Comment: I guess we'd need to use && as it seems the user wants to filter out toyota and bmw. Also Array is a reserved word.